# How to make a file of functions in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am trying to make a util.js file in React which will contain only functions. And I want to use that in my another file. I tried:

1) util.js

```
export function square(x){
    return x * x;
}
```

2) main.jsx

```
import { square } from "./util";
console.log(square(11));
```

I am getting a type error: **TypeError: _input.square is not a function**

Can someone tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: Working as expected. Demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vhmw4g?file=index.js. I dont see any issue

Comment: Yes, this code is fine. There was some another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one seems to be answering your actual question, which is why your code *isn't* working.

You example seems valid, it sounds like you've got something else going on, as indicated by the `_input` part of the error.

- Are you sure you're not redeclaring `square` somewhere?
- Are you instead calling something like `input.square()` in your code?
- Can you put together a full, reproducible answer?

Comment: Thanks. This code is correct. There was some another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare function like this:

```
export const square = (x) => {
 return x * x;
}
```

And you can use that function like this:

```
import { square } from "./util.js";
console.log(square(11));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm personaly using Helper class for those things

Helper.js

```
export default class Helper {
  static square(x){
    return x * x;
  }
}
```

Somewhere else in code

```
import Helper from './Helper'
Helper.square(15)
```

and it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
In util.js

```
export const square = (x) => {
 return x * x;
}

export const cube = (x) => {
 return x * x * x;
}
```

And in main.js

```
import * as Util from "./util";
console.log(Util.square(11));
console.log(Util.cube(11));
```